# Line of code ignored in function

Tags: actionscript-3, timeline

Ok. Super weird issue...

I have a function that is called when one movieclip is placed on another.  This code is on the timeline for the movieclip:

```
function eventWhenPlacedOn(){
   trace("placed item!");
   gotoAndStop(2);
   placedItem=true;
   trace(placedItem+" "+currentFrame);
   Globals.itemsArr[3].hideItem();
}
```

All of the code works except the gotoAndStop. The items hides correctly like the last line tells it to and placedItem is set to true, but it never changes to frame 2! It even traces "true 1"!  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and it's driving me crazy.  Any answers for this?

Comment: are you sure there is more than one frame?  It may not actually move the playhead to frame 2 until the next frame render (but I think that is unlikely). You'd need to post your .fla for more help I think.

Comment: are you trying to move the frame in the movieclip, or the swf itself? this will try and move the frame in the swf (assuming that the code is on the timeline)